# IP Configuration for a 10G Direct Link via NIC?

Tags: linux, networking, nic

I'm interested in setting up my 10G NIC, but am not sure 100% how to (OS: Manjaro KDE).

The driver is detected:

```
[manjaro manjaro]# inxi -n
Network:   Device-1: MYRICOM Myri-10G Dual-Protocol NIC driver: myri10ge 
           IF: enp6s0 state: down mac: 00:60:dd:45:7c:7c 
           Device-2: MYRICOM Myri-10G Dual-Protocol NIC driver: myri10ge
```

, but no IP address is assigned:

```
[manjaro manjaro]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp10s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:4b:fe:df:6c:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.223/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp10s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c010:ba07:bfc1:8235/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:60:dd:45:7c:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:60:dd:45:7c:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wlp9s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:8a:64:4a:5b:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 34:cf:f6:e3:e3:4c
```

How can I assign an IP address and complete the direct 10G connection between one computer and the other?

**Should I use the `ip` utility or `netplan`, and can you show how you would configure it?**

Strangely enough, the myri10ge driver package can't be found on the other Manjaro computer though.

System Specs:

```
System:    Host: DawnSkyFoundry Kernel: 5.10.36-2-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.0 
           Desktop: N/A Distro: Manjaro Linux base: Arch Linux 
Machine:   Type: Server System: Dell product: PowerEdge R7425 v: N/A serial: <superuser required> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 02MJ3T v: X30 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell v: 1.15.0 
           date: 09/11/2020 
CPU:       Info: 2x 32-Core (4-Die) model: AMD EPYC 7601 bits: 64 type: MT MCP MCM SMP arch: Zen 
           rev: 2 cache: L2: 32 MiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 560967 
           Speed: 1198 MHz min/max: 1200/2200 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1198 2: 1197 
           3: 2687 4: 2664 5: 2693 6: 2682 7: 1197 8: 2693 9: 2675 10: 2687 11: 2685 12: 2656 
           13: 2684 14: 2680 15: 2682 16: 2085 17: 2686 18: 2603 19: 2692 20: 2691 21: 2476 22: 1197 
           23: 2690 24: 2690 25: 2688 26: 2693 27: 2689 28: 2687 29: 2692 30: 2693 31: 2686 32: 2692 
           33: 2692 34: 2691 35: 2233 36: 2711 37: 2690 38: 2683 39: 2692 40: 2680 41: 2689 42: 2598 
           43: 2691 44: 2675 45: 2692 46: 2081 47: 2735 48: 2692 49: 2689 50: 2684 51: 2693 52: 2680 
           53: 2685 54: 2694 55: 2673 56: 2663 57: 2688 58: 2689 59: 2624 60: 2689 61: 2695 62: 1198 
           63: 2606 64: 2694 65: 2715 66: 2691 67: 2693 68: 2665 69: 2685 70: 2685 71: 2273 72: 2694 
           73: 2678 74: 2692 75: 2692 76: 2691 77: 2622 78: 1197 79: 2694 80: 2692 81: 2688 82: 2691 
           83: 2687 84: 2694 85: 2677 86: 2688 87: 2689 88: 2694 89: 2694 90: 1198 91: 1198 92: 2688 
           93: 2662 94: 2287 95: 2693 96: 2692 97: 2631 98: 2690 99: 2687 100: 1197 101: 2686 
           102: 2677 103: 2686 104: 2629 105: 2040 106: 2692 107: 2692 108: 2687 109: 2694 110: 2662 
           111: 2684 112: 2633 113: 2691 114: 2692 115: 2693 116: 1850 117: 2691 118: 1197 119: 2692 
           120: 2687 121: 2671 122: 2692 123: 2675 124: 2706 125: 2673 126: 2667 127: 2686 128: 2627 
Graphics:  Device-1: Matrox Systems Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics driver: mgag200 v: kernel 
           bus-ID: 03:00.0 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting resolution: 1600x900~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.1.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.3 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Message: No device data found. 
           Sound Server-1: JACK v: 0.125.0 running: no 
           Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 14.2 running: yes 
           Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.28 running: yes 
Network:   Device-1: Intel I350 Gigabit Network vendor: Dell 4P I350-t rNDC driver: igb v: kernel 
           port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.0 
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: b8:ca:3a:64:a4:b8 
           Device-2: Intel I350 Gigabit Network vendor: Dell 4P I350-t rNDC driver: igb v: kernel 
           port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.1 
           IF: eno2 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: b8:ca:3a:64:a4:b9 
           Device-3: Intel I350 Gigabit Network vendor: Dell 4P I350-t rNDC driver: igb v: kernel 
           port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.2 
           IF: eno3 state: down mac: b8:ca:3a:64:a4:ba 
           Device-4: Intel I350 Gigabit Network vendor: Dell 4P I350-t rNDC driver: igb v: kernel 
           port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.3 
           IF: eno4 state: down mac: b8:ca:3a:64:a4:bb 
           Device-5: MYRICOM Myri-10G Dual-Protocol NIC driver: N/A port: N/A bus-ID: 44:00.0 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 92.6 TiB used: 8.6 TiB (9.3%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: WDS100T2B0C-00PXH0 size: 931.51 GiB 
           temp: 29.9 C  
Partition: ID-1: / size: 512 GiB used: 16.75 GiB (3.3%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
           ID-2: /home size: 512 GiB used: 16.75 GiB (3.3%) fs: btrfs dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1 
Swap:      ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 419.01 GiB used: 5.1 GiB (1.2%) dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 40.5 C mobo: 0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 3927 Uptime: 1d 2h 36m Memory: 503.63 GiB used: 65.46 GiB (13.0%) 
           Init: systemd Compilers: gcc: 10.2.0 Packages: 1224 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.8 inxi: 3.3.04
```

Comment: You configure it however you want. But you also need to plug in a cable.

Comment: A cable is plugged in :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you run KDE, there is a graphic way to setup the NIC, probably based on `nm-applet` or itself.

If you prefer command line, using `ip`:

```
ip addr add {ip/subnet, ie 192.168.1.2/24} dev enp6s0
ip link set enp6s0 up
```

`nmcli`:

```
nmcli device modify enp6s0 ipv4.method manual
nmcli device modify enp6s0 ipv4.addresses {ip/subnet, ie 192.168.1.2/24}
```

Regarding your 2nd server: The kernel module must be available, but apparently firmware is missing. You could search for an installed package for Myri on the 1st server and install the same on 2nd. Or manually, look for the firmware inside `/lib/firmware` on 1st server. a .bin or .fw file named like Myri and copy it over.

Comment: So after the driver is installed on the second one, I can send packets / data to it using the IP that was set up?

Comment: Yes, sure. The firmware, not the driver, I'm pretty sure that's what you're missing. Insert a cable between the two NICs and you'll be good to go. No need to find a cross cable on modern NICs; or you could use a switch, for more connections. That's enough to send packets. Nevertheless, for real data, ie copy some files, you'll also need a server/protocol like, NFS, FTP, SMB.